# What situation will throw exception　＂WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, localhost): scala.util.control.BreakControl＂

Tags: scala

Why is this code throwing an exception?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: avoid using `break` in Scala.

`break` is internally implemented by throwing an exception. 
It can badly interact with the outer code. Seems that Spark is one more example of such behavior.

Also please attach code samples using stackowerflow markup. https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting